# j {name: "ServiceWorkerQuietError", message: "Service workers can only progress forward."}

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger

I'm trying to use the [Send to Messenger](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/plugin-reference/send-to-messenger) plugin, but I'm getting this error:

```
j {name: "ServiceWorkerQuietError", message: "Service workers can only progress forward."}
```

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>

<script>

  FB.Event.subscribe('send_to_messenger', function(e) {
    // callback for events triggered by the plugin

  });
</script>

</head>


<body>

<script>

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId: "XXX",
        xfbml: true,
        version: "v2.6"
      });

    };

    (function(d, s, id){
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>

<div class="fb-send-to-messenger" 
  messenger_app_id="XXX" 
  page_id="XXX" 
  data-ref="" 
  color="blue" 
  size="large">
</div> 


</body>

</html>
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Did any of you 2 found a solution?